# how to find the dynamic xpath for multiple tags along with text inside the div

Tags: java, selenium

Here my scenario is when I click on save button, saved successfully message will displayed on top of the page and after 2 sec it will be fade out. Now I have to verify the text "Saved Successfully".

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade in" style="text-align: center">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"/>
Saved Successfully
</div>

String txt=d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-success fade in']")).getText();
```

When I try with the code the output is :

```
"x
Saved Successfully"
```

Please any one can give the proper xpath to get the below message like

```
Saved Successfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String txt = "x \nSaved  Successfully";
String [] parts = txt.split("\\n");
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

Output:

```
Saved  Successfully
```

You are splitting the text by new line (`\n`) and the second part of the split is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the text from the i tag.So, You can change the xpath as below.

```
String txt=d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-success fade in']/i")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector which is

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".fa.fa-check")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by css selector ".alert i":

```
String successText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".alert i")).getAttribute("innerText").trim();
```

Adding trim at last will make sure that no extra space should be present while getting the text.